# String split with default delimiter vs user defined delimiter

Tags: python, split

I tried a simple example with string split, but get some unexpected behavior. Here is the sample code:

```
def split_string(source,splitlist):
    for delim in splitlist:
        source = source.replace(delim, ' ')
    return source.split(' ')

out = split_string("This is a test-of the,string separation-code!", " ,!-")
print out
>>> ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'of', 'the', 'string', 'separation', 'code', '']
```

As you can see, I got an extra empty string at the end of the list when I use space as delimiter argument for split() function. However, if I don't pass in any argument for split() function, I got no empty string at the end of the output list.

From what I read in python docs, they said the default argument for split() is space. So, why when I explicitly pass in a ' ' as delimiter, it creates an empty string at the end of the output list?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If sep is not specified or is None, **a different splitting algorithm** is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result **will contain no empty strings** at the start
>   **or end** if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

That may happen if you have multiple spaces separating two words.
For example,

```
'a    b'.split(' ') will return ['a', '', '', '', 'b']
```

But I would suggest you to use split from re module. Check the example below:

```
import re
print  re.split('[\s,; !]+', 'a b !!!!!!! ,     hello ;;;;; world')
```

When we run the above piece, it outputs ['a', 'b', 'hello', 'world']