# What is wrong with this program? Why did number and totalLength 0?

Tags: python-3.x

why is it that the number and totalLength still 0? What am I doing wrong. It should have changed due to the for line in lines statement

```
def cleanedup(s):
    alphabet= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    cleantext = ''
    for character in s.lower():
        if character in alphabet:
            cleantext += character
    else:
            cleantext = ' '
    return cleantext

import shelve

shelf = shelve.open('books')
lines = shelf['Pride and Prejudice']
shelf.close()

number = 0
totalLength = 0

for line in lines:
    for word in cleanedup(line).split():
        number += 1
        totalLength += len(word)

print(totalLength, number)
```

Comment: What are `lines` and `cleanedup`?  How are we supposed to know what your code is doing if you don't show us all of it?

Comment: What is `lines` and `cleanedup`?  Please create a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited it.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the main problem with your script:

```
        for character in s.lower():
            ...
        else:
            cleantext = ' '
```

I'm not sure this is the right position for the `else`, in your case you've put it after the for loop, so `cleantext` will be reset *each time you run this function* because your for loop has no `break` statement inside. [More info on `for ... else ...`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html)

---

Although that might not be what you want (question is a little unclear), the following code works:

```
def cleanedup(s):
    alphabet= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    cleantext = ''
    for character in s.lower():
        if character in alphabet:
            cleantext += character
    return cleantext


lines = ['lorem ipsum dolor sin amet', 'foo bar']

number = 0
totalLength = 0
for line in lines:
    for word in cleanedup(line).split():
        number += 1
        totalLength += len(word)

print(totalLength, number)
```

Output:

```
>>> 28 2  # 28 = total number of characters, 2 = total number of lines
```

---

PS: Next time, provide a more concise example that demonstrates the problem, instead of using an external file.

Comment: I think its missing import urllib.request somewhere. The lines Im trying to access is the lines of pride and prejudice onthe web and from the web get the totalLength and number

Comment: ..that's a completely different problem. If you have problems with `urllib`, then you should post another question and be more clear. Here, the counting function had some issues, however if that's not your main problem then create another question, be more precise, add some sample code that addresses the problem you want to solve, and add an error traceback. This way, you'll have much more chance to get the solution you actually want. On the other hand, if you think this answer improved your counting function, I'd be glad if you accepted it :)

Comment: How to accept your accept your answer? Golden star?

Comment: @AllanChen [To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) I hope you'll find an answer to your actual problem ...I can have a look at it if you post the link for the new question here.

Comment: Ok I did it, its fine found the answer.

Comment: `split()` should not be a problem, as it will split by whitespace when the argument `sep` is defaulted to `None` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271645/python-string-split-with-default-delimiter-vs-user-defined-delimiter))

Comment: @JingjieYANG Thanks for the comment, fixed.